# Get requested URL in Startup.cs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have multiple hostname binding on my IIS web site.
And I want to do some base setup during running Startup.cs, that should be dependent on what url has been called.

Lets say there is http://red.webapp.com and http://blue.webapp.com bindings to the same web site.

I tried to get url :

```
   var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
   var url = request.Url.Scheme;
   var auth = request.Url.Authority;
```

However as auth I have 127.0.0.1.

Is it possible to somehow get url that user tried to access?

Thank you.

Comment: Startup is an *application-wide* thing that happens once when the application starts. It doesn't make much sense to determine the URL that started the application as it won't happen very often. If you want to do something *per request*, consider making a [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters).

Comment: @NightOwl888, thank you for that information. Main reason for checking request url on startup.cs was to change azure signin policy during initialization, but I thought that each user when accessing website for the first time in session activate startup.cs. But looks like it not the case.